# Overriding styles in different values files

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using the new fontFamily attribute so that I can control the weight of font used.  Because this was only introduced in API level 16 I've created a styles file in values-v16.  It seems a bit silly to declare the colour, size etc in both values and values-v16 but it is necessary for all styling to be applied.  Is there someway to declare font family in the values-v16 styles file and inherit the colour, size etc from the values version of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a style inheritance. You can put all of the common (non-API specific) styles into a parent and inherit this in each of the children.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

```
<style name="v16" parent="CommonStyle">
```

Common file:

```
<style name="CommonStyle" >
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'd tried inheritance a different away.

What I've ended up with is to move the common styles into a style and then have the existing styles in values and values-v16 inherit from the new style.

It means in values I have an empty tag but this is better than having the styles duplicated.